# Sharepoint web part: type could not be found/registered as safe

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, web-config, safecontrols

I have a SharePoint web part (essentially just a "Hello World" app) that I just created and am having a problem deploying it. I have signed the .dll, created the .dwp, and registered it as a safe control in web.config. I am able to add it to the Web Part Gallery and add the details for it; however, when I attempt to add it to a page, I get the following error:

> A Web Part or Web Form Control on this
>   Page cannot be displayed or imported.
>   The type could not be found or it is
>   not registered as safe.

Following is my .dwp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
   <Assembly>SimpleWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=################</Assembly>
   <TypeName>MyWebParts.SimpleWebPart</TypeName>
   <Title>My Simple Web Part</Title>
   <Description>A simple Web Part</Description>
</WebPart>
```

and the entry I added to web.config:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="SimpleWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=################" Namespace="MyWebParts" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

I also tried using wildcards for the namespace, which didn't help. I have even tried setting the web.config trust level to "Full" (which I would never do in production, but tried to attempt to narrow down the problem) and still had no luck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Uh, this might be a stupid question, but do you have the actual public key token in your files in lieu of a bunch of hashes? ...It's called "public" for a reason.

Comment: That's not a stupid question at all. I do have the actual key in place of those hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you deploying your webpart using a SharePoint Solution (.wsp file)?  Check out [WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder)  if you aren't.  We also use [SharePoint Installer](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller)  Between the two, a lot of the problems (whether stemming from human error or otherwise) in deployments, like your problem have been resolved in our environment.

Comment: The SharePoint SmartTemplates that I'm using make use of the WSPBuilder and SharePoint Installer. They are awesome tools and cleared my problem up right off the bat. Thanks!

Comment: Being as there are so many people who are having this problem, I thought I would provide a link to SharePoint SmartTemplates as well: http://smarttemplates.codeplex.com/Wikipage. It's a fantastic tool that takes advantage of both the WSPBuilder and SP Installer, and makes deployment completely painless and consistent.

Answer (score 33):

One possibility is that types names are not in sync with the .webpart file. For ex.

In the **.webpart** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Namespace.Class1, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
```

and in the **.cs** file:

```
namespace Namespace
{
    public class Class2 : WebPart
```

and in the **SharePointProjectItem.spdata** file:

```
  <SafeControl Assembly="Class2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9385058ce1ee51a9" Namespace="Namespace" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

you get the idea: triple-check names consistency across all project artifacts.

Comment: With me it was the SharepointProjectItem.spdata file under the Visual Web Part that contained the wrong namespace. Easy to overlook!

Comment: My web part was initially called VisualWebPart1. I had renamed it, but the 5th line of the .webpart (where it says Namespace.Class1 above) still referred to VisualWebPart1. Find in files helped (as did this answer).

Comment: I had the same issue when I tried to customize the Namespace to NOT include the Web Part name. Personally, a Namespace should not include the name of the class, that is not the standard everywhere else in Microsoft land. The SharepointProjectItem.spdata file needs to be changed as well. Recommend this be marked as the answer!

Comment: This solved my issue; I had originally made a type and named the project "WeFormBla" instead of "WebFormBla" and had not changed that everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have the Web Part class as Public, might sound silly but I faced once. Also  try to populate the web part from the Web part Gallery .

Comment: I did double-check that, and the class it uses is indeed public. Being as it is manually installed, it already shows up in the gallery itself, and I can't populate it from the "New Web Parts" section.

Comment: not quite my problem but close enough for me to look in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I also saw this problem when I changed the namespace for my WebPart assembly, and the namespace wasn't updated in all of the source files in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try deploying it to the GAC?

Comment: My first thought - where is the DLL on the server?  Local bin directory or the GAC?

Comment: The .dll is located in the bin directory on the SharePoint server. I tried installing the .dll to the WINDOWS\assembly directory, and though it installed fine, I still was unable to add the control to a page. I am working with SharePoint on a specific port (one other than 80) and assumed that I could install the .dll to the \bin\ directory in the folder for that port, but there's no joy either way.

Comment: I do not understand why I'm not seeing the .dll in the "New Web Parts" section when I move it to WINDOWS\Assembly. It should show up in the list so that I can populate my Web Parts gallery with it, shouldn't it?

Comment: I ended up having success by using the SharePoint SmartTemplates tool made available through CodePlex. I would still like to know why I am unable to achieve this manually, but for now I am able to continue this project so I'll look into it later. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: Geo, I answered a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754006/is-sharepoint-local-bin-deployment-possible/1757444#1757444

Answer (score 1):

Ok , this may be very late but will be useful for the rest.  I created a webpart and was getting the error "A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe."

I figured that I was using a Chart inside this webpart and once I removed the reference of the chart, it worked.  So, the Chart control has to be also marked as typesafe.

Make sure all the references in the webpart are type safe.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you change the name of the web part from VisualWebPart1 to MyNewWebPart.  After doing a Search and Replace over the entire solution, rename all of the files and folders with VisualWebPart1 to MyNewWebPart.  The problem is caused by the file SharePointProjectItem.spdata not being updated.  Open SharePointProjectItem.spdata and replace VisualWebPart1 with MyNewWebPart.  This fixes the problem in most cases.

Open every file in the solution and verify that there are no references to VisualWebPart1.  If there are, change them manually to MyNewWebPart.

Answer (score 0):

Geo,

It's been a while since I worked with Web Parts but I laid out the steps here:

http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/webpart

Maybe there's something there that can help.

Anthony :-)

Comment: You've got some interesting points in that article that I hadn't yet been exposed to, particularly some of the settings in web.config that can cause problems. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Scarborough already mentioned, this can happen if you change the **namespace** and don´t update all source files (as this is not done automatically). Just for illustration, in my case the problem was that the webpart class had a new namespace **a.b** but I forgot to update this in the **webpart file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
<metaData>
             //update below!
  <type name="a.b.yourClass, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />

  <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
</metaData>
<data>
 <properties>
    <property name="Title" type="string">your Title</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string">your Description</property>
  </properties>
</data>
 </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have already found the solution, that's great. But here is a tip for someone who is searching for more. If you added a new webpart or a visual webpart and just replace the namespace in the files such as code files or Element.xml or even *.webpart file you might still face this issue. The reason is, as mentioned somewhere above, the namespace was not changed in* .spdata file, which is a file created by Visual studio itself. Just to be sure go check in the **Virtual Directories** in the inetroot. If the namespace is still the older one, do a search in your Solution and find out the conflicting one. Most probably in the project.spdata file, which everyone tends to ignore.